# ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently using Python ver 3.12, and I've been installed lots of things using `pip` install but most of them display the same error that I don't know how to fix it even though that I've downgraded the version to 3.8 and 3.9 or using the newest version, I've been using `pip install pyproject-toml` But it's still not working.
In this example i've installed the discord.py

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 (from discord.py)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\hoang\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (23.1.0)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (32 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\hoang\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (3.6)
Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
Using cached frozenlist-1.4.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (50 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running egg_info
      writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\hoang\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0k190i2x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've been using `pip install pyproject-toml`.

But it's still not working.

Comment: *I'm currently using Python ver 3.12, and I've been installed lots of things using pip install but most of them display the same error that I don't know how to fix it even though that I've downgraded the version*  What things did you install? What version did you downgrade to? Are you using a venv?

Comment: I'm install discord.py or openai but it display the same error even though that i've downgraded to 3.8 or 3.9 version

Comment: Are you using a venv?

Comment: No, I'm install it directly on my laptop, not using any venv

Comment: Can you try to use a venv? Create a Python 3.8 venv by running `python3.8 -m venv venv-name`. Then activate your venv by running `venv-name\scripts\activate` if you're using another windows. For more information on venv see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Then you can `pip install discord.py`. Ooenai should work well with your python 3.12. just follow similar steps and try using venvs to see if that helps. If you're not on windows, you may need similar commands to activate your venv as seen in the link

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with pyTelegramBotAPI dependencies. Same error had when tried to build image in docker. Downgraded to python:3.11-alpine and freeze in requirements multidict>=6.0.4 fix this problem. Hope, this can help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm try install python3.12-dev is resolved it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled version 3.12 and installed python 3.11.7 and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error trying to install [Nextcord](https://nextcord.dev/) with Python 3.12.

According to [an issue on Nextcord's discord server](https://discord.com/channels/881118111967883295/1200756689809461360/1200757337841995826), this problem is due to the fact that some C extension packages take time to have their wheels built when new Python versions release.

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to not use the lastest version of Python (3.11 worked perfectly for me).

If it doesn't work or for some reason you absolutely need to use the latest version of python, you can download and install the wheels [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (unofficial) if available.

Another option is to build them yourself.
Start by downloading and installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools from the URL in the error message.
After installing, it should open the build tools installation menu. Switch to the Individual components tab at the top.
Roughly half way down the list, find and select the latest version of MSVC build tools for your CPU architecture, most likely x64/x86.
At the end of the list, find and select the latest Windows SDK for your Windows version.
Click Install at the bottom and you should then be able to build your packages. You may need to restart your terminal/editor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a compilation error for `multidict`'s binaries. The [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/) suggests skipping compilation, although this may cause your code to run *"about 20-50 times slower depending on the usage scenario"*. You have to set `MULTIDICT_NO_EXTENSIONS=1`, so in Windows (which you seem to be running on) in PowerShell you'd do something like

```
$Env:MULTIDICT_NO_EXTENSIONS=1; pip install multidict
```

Alternatively, you could try installing the necessary build tools [following this guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29) and hope it works.